# How can I avoid escape characters in a Windows path in a Python logging config file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, configuration

I'm storing the path for the log file to be generated in a config file to make it easy to change at the time of deployment. However, currently the code is expecting \\ in the Windows path as shown in the existing config below (see args).

```
...
        [handler_fileHandler]
        class = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level = DEBUG
        formatter = simpleFormatter
        args = ("C:\\absolute\\path\\to\\logs\\app.log",'w', 0, 5)
...
```

The python code that reads this file:

```
logging.config.fileConfig("logging.ini", disable_existing_loggers=False)
```

Is there a way where I could instead just use a "standard" Windows path \ and have python still be able to read it? Maybe switch in code somewhere or some other mechanism? The aim being that in case the user chooses to change the path in the config file, they may not adhere to the \\ requirement and the app will crash. This app will only run in a Windows environment.

Desired config file args:

```
...
    [handler_fileHandler]
    class = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    level = DEBUG
    formatter = simpleFormatter
    args = ("C:\absolute\path\to\logs\app.log",'w', 0, 5)
...
```

Currently if I change the path from \\ to \ in the config file, I get the following error at runtime:

```
 File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\logging\config.py", line 79, in fileConfig
    handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\logging\config.py", line 142, in _install_handlers
    args = eval(args, vars(logging))
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: I think forward slashes should work assuming you have a recent version of windows. If not, try using raw strings.

Comment: Yes but forward slashes are not intuitive to the standard Windows user as in Windows paths are typically based on a single backslash: "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\logging\config.py" - just trying to avoid having to educate the end user to either use double backslash or single forward slash, both of which are not intuitive standard Windows paths

Comment: Why are your (non-programmer?) end users directly modifing the logging config in the first place?

Comment: Noted - I believe it's probably for best to give them a UI to make this change rather than do it directly - I felt the config file was self explanatory to make the changes directly - but it seems introducing a user-friendly step to avoid this problem makes sense